# The layout rules align_parent_end property does not show as true

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

At a point in my app I'm cycling through the objects on screen and checking if they're the last object in that line. To do that, I'm checking the Align Parent End property (which is checked for the last widget in each line). Here's part of my activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Average Temperature:"
        android:id="@+id/AverageTemperatureText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TemperaturesText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/AvgTempNum"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/AverageTemperatureText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/AverageTemperatureText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TempMiddle"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:editable="false"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:maxLength="7"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/TotalObservedVolumer"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/FreeWaterVolume"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/FreeWaterVolume"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                                       ^^^^ Right here. It's true.
```

You get the idea. Then, in my code, I'm cycling through the relative layout children, then for each view on it, checking it for that particular property. If it's true, I'm supposed to do something. But with the code I have, it's always false. So what am I doing wrong? Here it is:

```
RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

for(int i = 0; i < relLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View view = relLayout.getChildAt(i);

    // Assess if it's the last field in that line
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    int[] rules = params.getRules();

    if (rules[RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END] == RelativeLayout.TRUE) {
        // my code
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, but in a curious way.

In my case, all the last fields on screen had Align Parent End flagged. So I found online this would be the way to do it:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
int[] rules = params.getRules();
if ((rules[RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END] == RelativeLayout.TRUE)) {
    // Do something about it            
}
```

Where `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END` stands for 21, according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

However, my code was returning false for that check. So I started displaying the value for the property, and it really was false. I tried this for a while, then I saw one of my edittexts returned true for it. But the activity xml showed this

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

in addition to alignParentEnd. Which didn't make sense, since alignParentRight is supposed to be rule 11, according to the same link above. 
So I devised this code to expose which rules where true, and put it in my code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 22; x++) {
    if (rules[x] == RelativeLayout.TRUE) Log.i("Property true:", String.valueOf(x));
}
```

Which gave me 11 for all fields, and 11 and 21 for the field that responded TRUE before. Remember, all fields had `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` in the activity xml.

So to fix my code, I'm now checking `rules[RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT]` and it works, but I strongly believe those two properties are switched somehow. Can anybody confirm? Or please englighten me on where I screwed up, which is more likely :)